# How to figure out the necessary and sufficient condition for being a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

suppose that $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ and that $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ ( so that $g$ has an isolated singularity at $\infty$). Give necessary and sufficient conditions on the singularity of $g$ so that $g(f(z))$ has a pole at $z_0$ and prove that your conditions are necessary and sufficient.

What I think is that: the sufficient and necessary conditions on the singularity of $g$ so that $g(f(z))$ has a pole at $z_0$ is $g(z)$ neither has an essential singularity at $\infty$ nor has a removable singularity at  $\infty$.

prove: $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ if $f(z_0)=\infty$ and hence if $1/f(z_0)=0$.
$g$ has an isolated singularity at $\infty$ implies that $g(f(z))$ has an isolated singularity. There are only three kinds of singularities. if $g(f(z))$ is not removable or essential at $z_0$, then it has to be a pole at $z_0$. This happens if and only if $g(z)$ neither has an essential singularity at $\infty$ nor has a removable singularity at  $\infty$.

I cannot think anything further, but I doubt there are further solution.